# How to create a range picker for a variable in Qlik?

Tags: data-visualization, visualization, qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I'm new to Qliksense and I would like to select and visualise all datapoints in my table based on the value of a variable called `NoOfPersons`, similar to the date-range picker. How can I do this? I have attached a sample image below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Custom Objects the Qlik Dashboard bundle select the variable input object

[image]

Then under the variable options select the slider option

[image]

I don't know how to make it look like your example but it will provide the functionality you want

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I implemented this but the visualisations in my sheet do not update according to the slider, do you know if there is any extra setting I have to configure?

Comment: The slider changes the value of a variable. It does not select values from the data. If you haven't used the variable in your expressions then they won't update if you change the variable value. perhaps you need a filter object but you won't be able to format it horizontally like you want it'll only work vertically